# Is there an online LDAP emulator?

Tags: ldap

I'm doing some homework with LDAP that consists of creating LDIF files, adding them to the LDAP server, and afterwards performing some searches and viewing the results.

To avoid installing LDAP in my computer, I'm wondering if there exists some LDAP emulator online service where I can execute these instructions.

I've seen something similar with "online sql emulator", but not anything about LDAP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another alternative is the in-memory directory server provided by the [UnboundID LDAP SDK](http://www.unboundid.com/products/ldap-sdk/), which I talk about [here](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/ldap-in-memory-directory-server-using-unboundid-ldap-sdk/). There is no need to install a server. [LdapListenerExample.java](https://code.google.com/p/ldap-sample-code/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/samplecode/memory/LdapListenerExample.java) gives an example of how to use the in-memory directory server. The example shows how to create the server, start it listening, load schema files listed as command line options, and load a file containing LDIF into the server database.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, I'm not aware of such a thing.

As an alternative, I'd suggest you use [OpenDS](http://opends.java.net/), which is very easy to deploy (e.g. via [Install with QuickSetup](https://www.opends.org/promoted-builds/2.2.1/install/QuickSetup.jnlp)) and to get rid of afterwards. It's `import-ldif`, `make-ldif` and `export-ldif` commands could be useful for your work.

Comment: OpenDS development has stopped, but the open source project is now developed as OpenDJ: http://opendj.forgerock.org/. OpenDJ can also be installed with Java Web Start and the QuickSetup : http://download.forgerock.org/downloads/opendj/2.4.4/install/QuickSetup.jnlp.

Comment: nope. doesnt work : java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://www.forgerock.org/downloads/opendj/2.4.4/install/QuickSetup.jnlp

Answer (score 0):

I recently wrote [godap](https://github.com/bradleypeabody/godap) - a very minimalistic LDAP server library in Go.  It doesn't read LDIFs, but you can easily make it response to bind and search operations.  (It also may provide insight into the LDAP protocol.)